# Compare two text files and return corresponding value

Tags: perl

I have two files... the first is a .txt file containing ids...

```
245406
12432
2343576
213543
Ouad1234
evm.1234
```

The second file contains text in the first column and ids in the second. Is there any way I can compare the two ids, find matches and return the corresponding text in the first column?

```
AUX    2398432
AUL    245406
```

So when I parse the two files, the script should match `245406` and return the corresponding text `AUL`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
open FH_TF_IDS, "<$ARGV[0]" or die $!; 
while (<FH_TF_IDS>) {
    chomp; 
    @fields=split("\t",$_);
    $hash{$fields[1]}=$fields[0];
} 
close FH_TF_IDS;

open IDS, "<$ARGV[1]" or die $!;
@ids=<IDS>; 
close IDS; 

foreach $id (@ids){ 
    $hash_count{$hash{$id}}++;
} 

foreach $family (sort (keys %hash_count)) {
    print "$family\t$hash_count{$family}\n";
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: use the id's as hash keys.

Comment: This question has been asked before. I am not motivated enough to search, but maybe you can do it for yourself and close this as a duplicate.

Comment: i tried that i wrote a script but i do not know where i am going wrong.

Comment: You can edit your question to fill in the gaps, make corrections etc. That has a better chance of being seen and taken into account than random chunks of code in a comment.

Comment: No you didn't. You gibberish in a comment field again. OTOH, I edited your question to include that code. See the difference?

Comment: And what happens when you run your script?

Answer (score 1):

user1364517,

I think you've done a nice job attempting to solve the problem.  There are, however, two issues I see.

1. Add `chomp @ids;` after `close IDS;` to remove the \n at the end of each array element.
2. Change `$hash_count{$hash{$id}}++;` to `$hash_count{$hash{$id}} = $id if $hash{$id};`

These minor changes will enable your program to work.

Here's a more 'hacky' (certainly less idiomatic) solution--just for the fun if it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;

{open my $file, "<$ARGV[0]" or die $!;
$hash{$2} = $1 while <$file> =~ /(.*)\t(.*)/;}

{open my $file, "<$ARGV[1]" or die $!;
map{print "$hash{$_}\t$_\n"}sort{$hash{$a} cmp $hash{$b}}
grep{$hash{$_}}map{s/\n\z//r}<$file>;}
```

Blocks are used so the files are closed when `my $file` falls out of scope.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are a beginner to the language.  There is something that may help you debug your program.

At the top of your script 'use Data::Dumper;'

Once you do that you'll be able to put in statements like 
print Dumper( $hash ) and print Dumper( $hash_count ) 
those 2 statements should allow you to see the bug you have in your program.

As a side note running this through perl -d is also an option and one you should definitely learn if you are going to continue with the language.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use Data::Dumper;

    open a1, "<$ARGV[0]";
    while(<a1>) {
        my @a = split " ", $_;

        open b1, "<$ARGV[1]";
        while(<b1>) {
            my @b = split "\n", $_;
            my @test = (split " ", $b[0]);
            if($test[1] == $a[0]) {
                print $test[0]."\n";
            }
        }
        close b1;
    }
```

give the following command in terminal

```
    perl test.pl a.txt b.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Several suggestions:

- Pick up a book on [Modern Perl](http://modernperl.net). Perl is an old language full of cruft. The way you program in Perl has changed over the years since it first came out in the 1980s. Unfortunately, too many people learn Perl from websites written back in the pre-Perl 5.0 days.
- Use `use strict;` and `use warnings;` in your program. This will catch most of your programming errors.
- Don't depend upon `$_`. It's global and can cause problems. `for (@people) {` looks neat, but it's better to do `for my $person ( @people )`.
- Use `/../` in `split` and `'...'` in `join`.
- Use *variables* for file handles. They're easier to pass to subroutines:

Here's your program:

I've rewritten your program in a more modern style, and it works pretty much what you had. I did a bit of error checking, but otherwise, it works:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);  # Nicer that print.
use autodie;          # Will automatically die on open and close errors

if ( @ARGV < 2 ) {
    die qq(Not enough arguments);
}

my $tf_id_file = shift;   # Use variable names and not `@ARGV` directly
my $id_file    = shift;   # Makes your program easier to understand 

open my $tf_ids_fh, "<", $tf_id_file;

my %hash;                # Not a good name for the variable, but that's what you had.
while ( my $line = <$tf_ids_fh> ) {
    chomp $line;         # Always chomp after a read
    my ( $text, $id ) = split /\s+/, $line;  # Use variable names, not @fields
    if ( not defined $id ) {           # Error checking
        die qq(Missing id field in line $. of tf_ids file);
    }
    $hash{$text} = $id;
}
close $tf_ids_fh;

open my $ids_fh, "<", $id_file;
my @ids = <$ids_fh>;
chomp @ids;
close $ids_fh;

my %totals;
for my $id ( @ids ) {
    if ( not exists $totals{ $hash{$id} } ) {   #Initialize hash before adding to it
        $totals{ $hash{$id} } = 0;
    }
    $totals{ $hash{$id} }++;
}

for my $family ( sort keys %totals ) {
    printf "%10.10s %4d\n", $family, $totals{$family};
}
```

I use [printf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html) which formats your print output a bit nicer than regular `print` does.